# What is the exact Excel Days360 algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, excel, vba

I'm porting some calculations from Excel to C# which use the Days360 function (the default/US method). Using the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360-day_calendar) as a guide, I came up with this code:

```
    public static int Days360(DateTime a, DateTime b)
    {
        var dayA = a.Day;
        var dayB = b.Day;

        if (IsLastDayOfFebruary(a) && IsLastDayOfFebruary(b))
            dayB = 30;

        if (dayA == 31 || IsLastDayOfFebruary(a))
            dayA = 30;

        if (dayA == 30 && dayB == 31)
            dayB = 30;

        return ((b.Year - a.Year) * 12 + b.Month - a.Month) * 30 + dayB - dayA;
    }

    private static bool IsLastDayOfFebruary(DateTime date)
    {
        if (date.Month != 2)
            return false;

        int lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, 2);
        return date.Day == lastDay;
    }
```

I tested it with a (small) range of inputs and the results mostly agree with Excel's native function except if I use 2015-02-28 for both a and b. My code returns 0 and Excel -2.

My result seems more reasonable but at this point, I'd prefer to calculate the exact same result as Excel. There might be other inputs where they disagree so I don't want to make a special case just for that date.

Does anyone know the exact algorithm that Excel uses?

EDIT: There was a glaring bug in the original code I posted which is unrelated to the question. I had already fixed that one but I copied from the wrong file when posting the question.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the algorithm Microsoft uses: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/235575

Comment: @Kevin that's great, if you create an answer, I'll accept it. It doesn't explain why Excel thinks there are -2 days between 2015-02-28 and 2015-02-28 but I can live with that.

Comment: I ran a test comparing the results of my code and Excel for every date pair between 1970 and 2050 and the only difference is when both dates are the last day in February. It seems Excel doesn't implement the first rule from the Wikipedia algorithm. Commenting it out produced results identical to Excel.

Comment: Sounds like you are good to go!

Comment: @Kevin That link appears to be broken.  Could you update it, please?

Comment: @BH - it seem the article no longer exists. Sorry for anyone looking for it :(

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360-day_calendar) the Microsoft Excel `Days360` function is equivalent to 30/360 BMA/PSA. So to get exact results as MS Excel we need to implement the BMA/PSA method. I have implemented the method.

```
private double Days360(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
{
    int StartDay = StartDate.Day;
    int StartMonth = StartDate.Month;
    int StartYear = StartDate.Year;
    int EndDay = EndDate.Day;
    int EndMonth = EndDate.Month;
    int EndYear = EndDate.Year;

    if (StartDay == 31 || IsLastDayOfFebruary(StartDate))
    {
        StartDay = 30;
    }

    if (StartDay == 30 && EndDay == 31)
    {
        EndDay = 30;
    }

    return ((EndYear - StartYear) * 360) + ((EndMonth - StartMonth) * 30) + (EndDay - StartDay);
}

private bool IsLastDayOfFebruary(DateTime date)
{
    return date.Month == 2 && date.Day == DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need, I found the solution in the function on line 51 of this phpexcel library
[dateDiff360](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/DateTime.php)

this is part of the class code for the calculation

```
    /**
 * Identify if a year is a leap year or not
 *
 * @param    integer    $year    The year to test
 * @return    boolean            TRUE if the year is a leap year, otherwise FALSE
 */
public static function isLeapYear($year)
{
    return ((($year % 4) == 0) && (($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0));
}
/**
 * Return the number of days between two dates based on a 360 day calendar
 *
 * @param    integer    $startDay        Day of month of the start date
 * @param    integer    $startMonth        Month of the start date
 * @param    integer    $startYear        Year of the start date
 * @param    integer    $endDay            Day of month of the start date
 * @param    integer    $endMonth        Month of the start date
 * @param    integer    $endYear        Year of the start date
 * @param    boolean $methodUS        Whether to use the US method or the European method of calculation
 * @return    integer    Number of days between the start date and the end date
 */
private static function dateDiff360($startDay, $startMonth, $startYear, $endDay, $endMonth, $endYear, $methodUS)
{
    if ($startDay == 31) {
        --$startDay;
    } elseif ($methodUS && ($startMonth == 2 && ($startDay == 29 || ($startDay == 28 && !self::isLeapYear($startYear))))) {
        $startDay = 30;
    }
    if ($endDay == 31) {
        if ($methodUS && $startDay != 30) {
            $endDay = 1;
            if ($endMonth == 12) {
                ++$endYear;
                $endMonth = 1;
            } else {
                ++$endMonth;
            }
        } else {
            $endDay = 30;
        }
    }
    return $endDay + $endMonth * 30 + $endYear * 360 - $startDay - $startMonth * 30 - $startYear * 360;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm also include the optional parameter `method`:

```
int startMonthDays = 0; 
int endMonthDays = 0; 
double diff = 0;
if(method.Equals("TRUE"))
{

    if(dtStartDate.getDay() < 30)
    {
        startMonthDays = (30 - dtStartDate.getDay());
    }
    else
    {
        startMonthDays = 0; 
    }

    if(dtEndDate.getDay() < 30)
    {
        endMonthDays = dtEndDate.getDay();
    }
    else
    {
        endMonthDays = 30;  
    }

    diff =  (dtEndDate.getYear() - dtStartDate.getYear())*360 +
                    (dtEndDate.getMonth() - dtStartDate.getMonth() - 1)*30 +
                    startMonthDays + endMonthDays;
}
else
    {
        if(DateCalendar.daysInMonth(dtStartDate.getYear(), dtStartDate.getMonth()) == dtStartDate.getDay())
        {
            startMonthDays = 0; 
        }
        else
        {
            startMonthDays = (30 - dtStartDate.getDay());
        }

        if(DateCalendar.daysInMonth(dtEndDate.getYear(), dtEndDate.getMonth()) == dtEndDate.getDay())
        {
            if(dtStartDate.getDay() < DateCalendar.daysInMonth(dtStartDate.getYear(), dtStartDate.getMonth()) - 1)
            {
                if(DateCalendar.daysInMonth(dtEndDate.getYear(), dtEndDate.getMonth()) > 30)
                {
                    endMonthDays = DateCalendar.daysInMonth(dtEndDate.getYear(), dtEndDate.getMonth());
                }
                else
                {
                    endMonthDays = dtEndDate.getDay();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(DateCalendar.daysInMonth(dtEndDate.getYear(), dtEndDate.getMonth()) > 30)
                {
                    endMonthDays = DateCalendar.daysInMonth(dtEndDate.getYear(), dtEndDate.getMonth()) - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    endMonthDays = dtEndDate.getDay();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            endMonthDays = dtEndDate.getDay();

        }

        diff =  (dtEndDate.getYear() - dtStartDate.getYear())*360 +
                    (dtEndDate.getMonth() - dtStartDate.getMonth() - 1)*30 +
                    startMonthDays + endMonthDays;
    }
```

with

```
public static int daysInMonth (int year, int month) 
{      
    if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) && month == 2) 
    {
        return 29;   
    }   
    else
    {
        return table[month - 1];  
    }
}
```

and

```
private static readonly int[] table = new int[]{ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm only interested in the default/US method. Does your version return the same results as Excel for the date I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Test the next

```
public static int Days360(DateTime a, DateTime b)
{
    var dayA = a.Day;
    var dayB = b.Day;

    if (IsLastDayOfMonth(a) && IsLastDayOfMonth(b)) {
        dayB = Math.min(30, dayB);
    } else if (dayA == 30 && dayB ==31) {
        DayB = 30;
    }

    if (IsLastDayOfMonth(a))
        dayA = 30;

    return ((b.Year - a.Year) * 360 + b.Month - a.Month) * 30 + dayB - dayA;
}

private static bool IsLastDayOfMonth(DateTime date)
{
    int lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
    return date.Day == lastDay;
}
```